# jquery wait for async call to be executed

Tags: javascript, settimeout, elevation

I am trying to get elevation data on click in google maps api.
for that following is what I have implemented.

```js
function getElevationtimeer(lat, lng) {
            returnvaluetime = "";
            elevationpoint = "";
            getElevation(lat, lng);
            setTimeout(ajax, 3000);
            return returnvaluetime;
}

function getElevation(lat, lng) {
            var locations = [];
            elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();
            var clickedLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            locations.push(clickedLocation);
            var positionalRequest = {
                'locations': locations
            }
            elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[0]) {
                        elevationpoint = results[0].elevation;
                    } else {
                    }
                } else {
                }
            })
            return returnvaluetime;
        }

function ajax() {
            if (elevationpoint != "")
                returnvaluetime = elevationpoint;
        }
```

Initially I am calling `getElevationtimeer` method.
From that I am calling first `getElevation` method, in which I am finding elevation for clicked location.
After that I am calling `ajax` method, in which I am assigning elevation value to the variable which I want to return from main method.

I can understand what is going wrong in above code.
Please help me what is possible way to implement the logic for getting elevation.

Comment: You may use promise to solve your issue http://kctang.github.io/blog/2015/05/09/understanding-javascript-promise-with-examples-no-more-callback-hell/

Comment: None of your functions return anything but empty strings or undefined variables. If you include some of the following I may be able to help:
* Your "main method" implementation
* Your AJAX implimentation

Comment: I am getting value from elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[0]) {
                        elevationpoint = results[0].elevation;
            })                             I am calling getElevationtimeer function from server side. So yes I am getting empty string on the server side. because elevator.getElevationForLocations takes time to be executed.                            ----OhAuth

Comment: @WebAshlarEmailTest `returnvaluetime` is not being set inside `getElevation()` so it will always return `undefined`.

Comment: Oh, so should I set it in side getElevatio()??? Right I have set it globally.